# Android Material Spinner with api 19

Tags: android, material-design, android-spinner

I want to apply theme to Spinner same as [this link](https://github.com/rey5137/Material/wiki/Spinner).

I am using:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I checked [this](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner) and [this also](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1707) but I am not getting exactly:

[image: to this image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting excact"?

Comment: i am not getting effects of onitem click

Answer (score 0):

Rey's library backports ripple effect, so it can be used with Rey's widgets. You need that as well. If the libraries you mentioned don't have ripples, you have to backport them by yourself.

Is there any reason you don't want to use the library you mentioned as the one with nice spinner?

By the way, material spinner should show menu on the widget, not below. The selected item's bounds should match the widget's bounds, if possible. More like this:

[image]

Or this (my implementation):

[image]